# Is there a function I can enable to have a Check List action item populate in multiple boards I select?

Tags: sorting, trello-cards, trello-boards, trello-lists

I have an "Active Projects" board that has about 60 lists each representing a company I manage. Each company has 1-5 cards representing projects we are working on. Each card has a "TO DO" checklist.

I would like to have a "Quick Look" board that self populates with tasks I define as "high priority" in their respective checklist folder for each company.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy a checklist on a board (Open card, "Add Checklist...", "Copy Items From..."), but there is no option to copy across boards, sorry. You might try out the [API](https://trello.com/docs) if you want something custom like that.

You can also copy boards ("Options" > "Copy Board..."), if that helps.